# Enter a string containing "!!" on a shell without it being interpretted

Tags: shell, zsh, sh

I'm trying to send a string that contains "!!" in it. However, every time I execute it on zsh, zsh replaces !! with the last command entered. How can I get zsh to not interpret "!!"? I have also confirmed the same thing happens when I just use sh.

Comment: use single quotes '!!'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried quoting your string with single quotes instead of double quotes?

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-double-quotes-don%27t-protect-exclamation-marks-545662/

```
bbbco (04:45 PM) ~/ $ echo "Exclamation!!"
echo "Exclamationecho "Exclamationecho 'Exclamation!!'""
Exclamationecho Exclamationecho Exclamation!!

bbbco (04:43 PM) ~/ $ echo 'Exclamation!!'
Exclamation!!
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried one backslash for every character?

```
\!\!
```

Preceding characters with backslash (one backslash per one character) should give in effect exactly this character, not replaced (it is not interpreted then).

Comment: to aid googling for the OP, it's called 'escaping'.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, quoting or escaping helps to prevent the history expansion in the current command line.

But, you can also use

```
unsetopt BANG_HIST
```

to disable the special treatment the character `!` completely. (Put this is your `~/.zshrc` to make it permanent.)